# Adding "ant-design-pro": "^2.3.2" and including it in project resulting in error

Tags: clojurescript, ant-design-pro, shadow-cljs

I'm getting the below error when I try to import `"ant-design-pro": "^2.3.2"` and use it in my ShadowCLJS project.

> The required JS dependency "./factoryWithThrowingShims" is not available, it was required by "node_modules/bizcharts/umd/BizCharts.js".

Confirmed that after removing the dependency and referece of `ant-design-pro` gets my app up and running properly.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: There is also a [Github issue with this problem](https://github.com/alibaba/BizCharts/issues/99), did you try the solution suggested there?

Comment: Why not going with a 5-ish release?